# Net core 6 Serialization and deserialization Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have created a web API. I have used Net Core 6 and Entity framework. In this method I want save two entities. StockPosition is saved but there is some problem  with StockTransaction. I ve got an error:

System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.IntPtr' instances are not supported. Path: $.TargetSite.MethodHandle.Value.
---> System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.IntPtr' instances are not supported.

The data dto:

```
public class StockPositionBuyDto
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int IdCurrency { get; set; }
   public decimal Count { get; set; }
   public decimal Price {get; set; }
   public decimal Fee { get; set; }

}

public class StockTransaction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public StockPosition Position { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public decimal Count { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public decimal Fee { get; set; }

    public Currency Currency { get; set; }
}


public IActionResult newStockPosition(StockPositionBuyDto dto) 
{
    try
    {
        string jwt = Request.Cookies["jwt"];

        var token = jwtService.verify(jwt);

        int userId = int.Parse(token.Issuer);


        User user = userRepository.findById(userId);
      
        Currency currency = this.currencyRepository.getById(dto.IdCurrency);
        
        StockPosition stockPosition = new StockPosition
        {
            Stock = this.stockRepository.getById(dto.Id),
            Count = dto.Count,
            User = user
        };

        

        StockPosition position = this.stockPositionRepository.create(stockPosition);

        
        StockTransaction transaction = new StockTransaction
        {
            Type = "buy",
            Count = dto.Count,
            Price = dto.Price,
            Fee = dto.Fee,
            Currency = currency,
            Position = position

        };

       
        StockTransaction transactionSaved =  this.stockTransactionRepository.create(transaction);

        return Ok("Ok");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Unauthorized(ex);
    }

}
```

The repository for saving.

```
public StockTransaction create(StockTransaction transaction)
{
    context.stockTransactions.Add(transaction);
    transaction.Id = context.SaveChanges();

    return transaction;
}
```

Comment: Your model doesn't contain an IntPtr. I suspect the controller is throwing an exception that you're not expecting, and you're trying to return that exception as json in `Unauthorized(ex)`. This is not a good practice, you should limit your `catch` blocks to only catch exceptions that you are expecting, and you shouldn't return a serialized exception in production code

Comment: transaction.Id = context.SaveChanges(); what are you trying to do on this line? SaveChanges returns the number of rows modified, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with:

```cs
...
catch(Exception ex) {
         return Unauthorized(ex)
    }
```

Method `Unauthorized` itself tries serialize `ex` and can not, throws error that you see.
Error msg `System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.IntPtr'....`  is definitely confusing in this case.
Try returning

```
...
catch {
    return new JsonResult(new {error=ex.Message});
}
```

will get proper error. Thanks @Andrew Williamson for pointing into right direction.